# Sending Email Based on Cell Value

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The email function works fine, but the code has the following error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (line 90, file "Code.gs") (last line) when the function checkValue was added.

Basically,  we want the email to send automatically when D2 is edited. We are hoping this will eliminate the need to allow permissions to send email every time a template is copied by an aid.

```
    function checkValue () {
var check = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
var rangeEdit =e.range.getA1Notation();
if(rangeEdit == "D2") {
  {
   
function email(checkValue) {
 
 

  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
 

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ClassA")
   
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow()
   
 
  var name = sheet.getRange("E4").getValue();
  var aid = sheet.getRange("E3").getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  var pemail = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
 
  var period = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
 var og= sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
 
 



  // Subject of email message
  var subject = "Grade Summary | " + og +"- " + period;

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  var body = "Hi " + name + ", "+ "<br><br> Please find the grade summary  attached for " + period + ". <br><br>  Let us know if you have any questions.<br><br>  Thank you,<br><br> " + aid;
     
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array
 
  // Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=True'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();


  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs;


    // Convert your specific sheet to blob
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');


  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());
   
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
 
      name:'class',
      bcc: aid,
      noReply: true,
      attachments:[blobs]    
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have enough closing brackets to terminate the function `checkValue`, thus it returns a syntax error.

Since your intent is to check the value first before sending the email, it is better if you separate the `email` function and call it from `checkValue` instead of enclosing it in an if statement. The parameter is not needed as well.

Also since you indicated that you need to send an email, you need an installable trigger. Create a trigger using the script service by running `createSpreadsheetEditTrigger()`, which will then run `checkValue()`.

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkValue')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function checkValue(e) {
  var rangeEdit = e.range.getA1Notation();
    if(rangeEdit == "D2") {
      email();
    }
}

function email() {
          // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address

          // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
          // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
          
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
          var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ClassA")
          
          var lrow = sheet.getLastRow()
          
        
          var name = sheet.getRange("E4").getValue();
          var aid = sheet.getRange("E3").getValue();
          var email = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
          var pemail = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
        
          var period = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
        var og= sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
        
        



          // Subject of email message
          var subject = "Grade Summary | " + og +"- " + period;

          // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
          var body = "Hi " + name + ", "+ "<br><br> Please find the grade summary  attached for " + period + ". <br><br>  Let us know if you have any questions.<br><br>  Thank you,<br><br> " + aid;
            
          var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
        Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
        Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array
        
          // Base URL
          var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

          /* Specify PDF export parameters
          From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
          */

          var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
          + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
          + '&portrait=True'                    // orientation, false for landscape
          + '&fitw=true'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
          + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
          + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
          + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
          + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

          var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();


          //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
          var blobs;


            // Convert your specific sheet to blob
            var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
              headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
              }
            });

            //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
            blobs = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');


          // Define the scope
          Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());
          
            MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
              htmlBody: body,
        
              name:'class',
              bcc: aid,
              noReply: true,
              attachments:[blobs]    
            });  
}
```

**References:**

[Installable Triggers | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Where in the code should this be inserted? And where else do I need a closing bracket?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the whole code segment. Since you need an installable trigger, I added another function to the answer that you should run manually.

Comment: Thanks. I need it to run automatically and not manually. Is that possible?

Comment: You only need to run ````createSpreadsheetEditTrigger()```` once. Then everything else should be checked automatically.

Comment: The data is supposed to pulled not from the active sheet but from another tab.

Comment: The trigger would not check the sheet name, it would only check if cell D2 in the active sheet is edited. Then the email function would pull the data from ClassA sheet.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, we want the email to send automatically when D2 is edited.

```
var rangeEdit =e.range.getA1Notation();
```

---

From what I see here it looks like you are trying to send an Email when the cell is changed, probably by using onEdit trigger.

You can't do that.

OnEdit belongs to simple triggers. Simple triggers can't call services that require authorization. Check here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers the Restrictions section.

---

If I'm wrong with what are you trying to do, please edit your post with the code, since "Carlos M" wrote in his reply that it can't compile.

Comment: Big thanks for indicating the restrictions!