# How to send google sheets email via Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My javascript works fine, but I am trying to create a template that will be copied by several people. The template javascript PDF's itself and sends to an assigned person. The issue is when the template is copied, it makes you allow permissions. We want the email to send from one specific email to prevent quota issues. We want to deploy the javascript code via Web App. Basically on the template would be linked to the website to send email from website. How do I go about doing this? I have tried several methods but nothing has worked.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.clientID;
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ClassA")
   
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow()
   
 
  var name = sheet.getRange("E4").getValue();
  var aid = sheet.getRange("E3").getValue();
  var email = sheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  var pemail = sheet.getRange("E2").getValue();
 
  var period = sheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
 var og= sheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
 
 



  // Subject of email message
  var subject = "Grade Summary | " + og +"- " + period;

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  var body = "Hi " + name + ", "+ "<br><br> Please find the grade summary  attached for " + period + ". <br><br>  Let us know if you have any questions.<br><br>  Thank you,<br><br> " + aid;
     
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array
 
  // Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace(ss.getId());

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=True'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();


  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs;


    // Convert your specific sheet to blob
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');


  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());
   
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
 
      name:'class',
      bcc: aid,
      noReply: true,
      attachments:[blobs]    
    });  
}   

  
  // Base URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */

  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=letter'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=True'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();


  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs;


    // Convert your specific sheet to blob
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs = response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + '.pdf');


  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());
   
 return ContentService.createTextOutput('Sent Email').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web ? You say "on the template would be linked to the website to send email from website" - I am having trouble understanding this. Could you provide maybe some screenshots and an example?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of how it should all flow: https://imgur.com/a/j5L0P50

Comment: Is it possible that you able to provide some of your code? See: [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you could provide the JavaScript you have so far, for example? This would be very helpful and would prevent me from having to construct an application from scratch to test - its also possible that I construct it, and then its not really what you want.

Comment: Its the same code from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780879/sending-email-based-on-cell-value

Comment: You should accept the answer from that question that solved your issue. But please edit this question to contain everything needed to answer this question, it is just Stack Overflow guidelines. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).